# In Alien franchise books/movies, ever any deliberate protection of humans by neomorphs?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus

I wonder if they have ever indicated sophistication like this, knowing that they need humans for breeding, they might, for example prevent a hull breech in space, etc.?

In Prometheus, although it seems pretty random that the "octopus" attacked the Engineer, it did indeed save Elizabeth and is it anywhere suggested that this was not random but that the creature, born from Dr. Shaw, was actually protecting her?